# Galois theory on multivariable polynomials

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, splitting-field

I have only learned Galois theory over rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$, in my algebra and/or algebraic number theory class, which helps study polynomials $f(x)$ over one-variable by studying their splitting fields. I had a question to see if we could study splitting fields of multivariable polynomial analogously.

1. If $f(x,y)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of two variables then, we could find a polynomial $F(x) \in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(x,y) = y^{m} F(\frac{x}{y})$. Here $m$ is the degree of $f(x,y)$. Then we could find splitting of $F(z) = (a_{1}z + b_{1}) \cdots (a_{m}z + b_{m})$ into linear factors and its splitting field. Note that $f(x,y) = (a_{1}x + b_{1}y) \cdots (a_{m}x + b_{m}y)$.
   Does it make sense say that the splitting field of $f(x,y)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(y)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(y)(a_{1}, \ldots , a_{m}, b_{1}, \ldots, b_{m})$, ignoring the $a_{j}, b_{j}$ that are already rationals?
2. If the answer to above is **YES**, how can we do this for non-homogeneous polynomial? If the answer to above is **NO**, is there any way to study the splitting field of multivariable polynomials?

I would also appreciate a lot if someone could point me to any relevant references.

Comment: If $f(x,y)$ contains the term $Ax^m$ then you can set $a_1=A$ and $a_i=1$ for all $i>1$ simply by scaling. With that in place the $b_j$s come from the splitting of $F$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ so they need not be rationals. You do get the splitting field in this way. We can define the splitting field of a polynomial $f(x,y)\in\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$ over $\Bbb{Q}(y)$ in the usual way by thinking that $f$ really is a polynomial in $\Bbb{Q}(y)[x]$. Or over $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ by switching the roles of the variables. So for example the splitting field of $y^2-x^3+x$ over $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ is $\Bbb{Q}(x,\sqrt{x^3-x})$.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an issue of uniqueness of degree for the splitting field for non-homogeneous polynomials? For example, when $f(x,y) = x^{2} - y^{3}$, we can take splitting field as either $\mathbb{Q}(x, \sqrt[3]{x^{2}})$ or $\mathbb{Q}(y, \sqrt{y^{3}})$. I am guessing these have been studied before.. @JyrkiLahtonen, do you want to give me some references?

Comment: All uniqueness of degree results require you to specify the base field. If you switch the base field from $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ to $\Bbb{Q}(y)$, all bets are off! Notice that if you want a splitting field of your $f$ over $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ you need to include a third root of unity. Much like when looking for a splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot give very good references for this stuff over $\Bbb{Q}$. I guess that if you search for *function fields* you will find something good. I predict that over $\Bbb{Q}$ you will quickly be redirected to *arithmetic geometry*. I find the case where we replace $\Bbb{Q}$ with a finite field very interesting. Michael Rosen has a nice book on *Number theory in function fields*. Henning Stichtenoth has a book (actually two) focusing on the applications to coding theory, but that's not everybody's cup of coffee.

Comment: Anyway, you will not get far without running into algebraic curves and *algebraic geometry.* It is much more tractable in the case of curves. A basic object of study will be the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=0$. Function fields are one of the tools for their study. Geometric concepts written and studied in terms of rings and fields is the game.

Comment: Caveat; Rosen and Stichtenoth **only** look at function fields over a finite field.