# Galois group of $x^3+t^2x-t^3$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$

Tags: solution-verification, galois-theory, splitting-field

**Question:**

Compute the Galois group of the polynomial $x^3+t^2x-t^3$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$ where $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is the field of rational functions in one variable over complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

**Answer:**

Let $f(x)=x^3+t^2x-t^3$. Then suppose $f(kt)=(kt)^3+t^2(kt)-t^3=0$. Thus, we obtain $k^3t^3+kt^3-t^3=0$, which yields that $k^3+k-1=0$. Now in $\mathbb{C}$, I can find three $k$ (not necessarily distinct) satisfying that relation. This shows that in fact $f$ splits into linear factors in $\mathbb{C}(t)$. Hence, the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$ must be $\mathbb{C}(t)$ itself. Therefore, $Gal(f)$ must be the trivial group.

Do you see any mistake in my proof? Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Similar but different](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4151399/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.

---

Because $f$ is homogeneous of degree three as a polynomial in two variables, it factors as
$$f(x)=(x-k_1t)(x-k_2t)(x-k_3t)$$
in the ring $\Bbb{C}(t)[x]$. Here $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are the complex zeros of the equation $$k^3-k+1=0$$ that you used. The roots $k_it$, $i=1,2,3$, are all in the base field $\Bbb{C}(t)$, so $\Bbb{C}(t)$ itself is the splitting field and the Galois group is trivial.